# Check box to update boolean value from show view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, view

There is a Problem model and a Note model.  Problems can have many notes.

Problem show view also shows the notes associated with that problem.  I would like to have a 'solution' checkbox beside a note which if can be ticked if that note solves the problem.  This would then update the boolean field, is_solution, in the notes table.  The code I have at the moment if failing on (notes_params) as :note node is nil.  Help gratefully received.

**show.html.erb**

```
<% @problem.notes.each do | note | %>
      <tr>
      <td>    <%= form_tag (problem_notes_solution_path(@problem, note)) do %>
                 <%= markdown(note.body) %><%= check_box_tag "is_solution", note.is_solution %>          
                 <%= submit_tag "Mark as Solved" %> 
                 <% end %></td>
 <% end %>
```

**notes_controller**

```
before_action :set_problem
before_action :set_note, :except => [ :index, :new, :create]

def solution
    @note.update_attributes(note_params)
    redirect_to @problem
end


private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_problem
      @problem = Problem.find(params[:problem_id])
      authorize @problem, :show?
    end

def set_note
@note = @problem.notes.includes(:user).find(params[:id])
  authorize @note
end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def note_params
  params.require(:note).permit(*policy(@note || Note).permitted_attributes).merge(:user => current_user)
end
```

**note_policy.rb**

```
def permitted_attributes
   if user.role == 'user'
    [ :body ]
   else
    [ :body, :time, :is_solution ]
   end
end
```

Comment: What is the value of note_params inside solution action when you submit the form? (use pry or print the value to the console - p note_params)

Comment: it is failing because the form_tag isn't passing a :note param, although @note is being created in the controller I think the params.require(:note) needs to see a note param  - don't know how to pass it one, or indeed whether form_tag is the right way of doing this....thank you for your time